Increase Accuracy of Magnetic Compass
How to increase the accuracy magnetic compass? Is there a good way using multiple ones?
I searched the Internet and Philip Werner suggested at Section Hiker web:

use the most current declination data for an area
use a declination adjustable compass (e.g., the Suunto M3 or Silva Ranger)
stay clear of iron/steel and electrical sources

This is with one compass. How about with multiple compasses? Sometimes, we used multiple sensors to increase accuracy (magnetic North) by compensating each other:

Characteristics of noise and error (average) by user, Skander H. in Cross Validate board
Inertia Measurment Unit in quadcopter (Kalman Filter) by user, JJM Driessen in Robotics board

I again searched the Internet, and the torque on each needle would be influenced by the other needle but not great amount by Simon Bridge at Quora.
I especially think about in the ocean or cave (I got an idea from the JPhi's question: Compass Working Underground?).
Regarding location of compass, for example Tesla car equipped with numerous optical cameras in left, right, top, front, back and etc. I am considering several compasses in various locations of the submarine or the cave exporting drone.

You also need to keep clear of magnetic rocks. Rather difficult if you're inside such rock. I've been caught out by this on the surface, luckily not when it mattered, but just sightseeing.

How much accuracy do you need and what for? In my experience, the hard part is following a compass course. Be it due to waves, gusts and drifts while sailing or crevasses on a glacier. If you get +-5 degrees, that is already pretty good. In a cave, that would be even worse, as the cave limits where you can go.

On the topic of multiple compasses, I would not expect to give any meaningful improvement. The problems with a compass are external influences, not the compass itself deviating by a single degree

@Manziel The accuracy probably depending on location in latitude. In degree, at the  latitude 0 I want to see less than one minute. Regarding multiple compass, is there way to calculate amount of external influence by another compass and different spot?

I wonder if you should clarify something: The ability of a compass to accurately align with magnetic north, versus your ability to correct magnetic north to true north? You mention them both but they are separate issues...

Also, maybe you can expand upon "we used multiple sensors to increase accuracy by compensating each other." If that is true, can you go into more detail?

The main limit would be your ability to read north on each compass, visually you won't get any useful information out without some maths, electronically read and you might be able to take some averages, but neither means anything without knowing the tolerances of the equipment and the conditions it is held under. E.g. hand-held compass measured by eye, will swing a few degrees with wobbles in your hand and movements from breathing etc even while standing still, even if precision is +/- 0.01 deg. Also what benefit is there to having more measurements?

@bob1 thanks for information. Regarding "knowing the tolerances of the equipment", some of equations, we don't need hardware characteristics like Kalman Filter (details: https://thekalmanfilter.com/kalman-filter-explained-simply/). For "benefit is there to having more measurements", except possible accuracy improvement, I guess we could detect large noise of the compass(es).

@CloudCho In that case Kalman filtering might work, but I still don't see that the tolerances of the equipment don't play into that equation - I'm no mathematician of any sort, but the uncertainty in the reading definitely looks like it plays into the calculation. In addition, why use multiple if using Kalman filtering, it would abrogate the need for multiple readings surely; wouldn't you be better off with sequential readings from one? After all, ships still only contain 1 (that I know of, also not an expert) which is compared to a gyrocompass regularly.

@bob1 Thanks for information of sailing case. Regarding "the uncertainty in the reading definitely looks like it plays into the calculation" yes I agree. For "wouldn't you be better off with sequential readings from one", I would get better value, but with the one compass, I may not overcome it's inacuracy from manufacturing. By the way, how manufacturer estimate the tolerance of the compass?
